# How does Excel.Application.Visible behave?

Tags: vb.net, excel, interop, visible

I'm designing a console application in VB.Net that needs to look through some excel files.  I would prefer to keep Excel hidden, but the code I have is not working the way I expected it to.

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application
Dim xlWkBk As Excel.Workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(dwgLogs(i), [ReadOnly]:=True)
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet = xlWkBk.Sheets("Detail")
With xlApp
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Visible = False
    .Application.Visible = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With
```

I'm not sure why, but only for a split second, the excel application opens and displays itself and then hides.  If I could, I would like it to not display at all.  Am I asking for too much, or am I not writing the code correctly?  Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.  By the way, my current Excel version is 2013.  I'm not sure if that would affect anything, but I figured I'd mention it.

Comment: Any luck setting the application properties *before* you open the workbook?

Comment: Unfortunately no...  I tried that, but it seemed that VB ignored the properties outright and left the application visible.

Comment: It is not supposed to be visible at all, regardless if you set the Visible property to False explicitly.  Consider that your Excel install has a wonky add-in.

Comment: That sounds like a good possibility.  I'll check to see if my add-ins are causing my problem.

Comment: You could also move the window to the bottom left so it doesn't show. This would require getting a windows handle and have it close it, or making sure the startup window position is already set for the app.

Answer (score 0):

Do your .Visible before interacting with the rest of the Excel application.

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application
xlApp.Visible = False
Dim xlWkBk As Excel.Workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(dwgLogs(i), [ReadOnly]:=True)
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet = xlWkBk.Sheets("Detail")
With xlApp
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Application.Visible = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not have the desired effect.  I tried this and still no luck.